# MDBootstrap vue.js modal transitions not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, mdbootstrap

i have downloaded mdbvue demo project from mdbootstrap website and found out that enter and afterEnter events in modal component doesn't work. To check this i have modified method which called by event with alert

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade"
    @enter="enter"
    @after-enter="afterEnter"
    @before-leave="beforeLeave"
    @after-leave="afterLeave" 
  >
    <component :is="tag" :class="wrapperClass" @click.self="away">
      <div :class="dialogClass" role="document" >
        <div :class="contentClass" :style="computedContentStyle">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </component>
  </transition>
</template>
```

---

```
    enter(el) {
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      alert();
      el.childNodes[0].style.transform = this.dialogTransform;
    },
```

However modal opens without any alerts. But alert in beforeLeave event works perfectly.

```
beforeLeave(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  alert();
  el.childNodes[0].style.transform = this.dialogTransform;
},
```

The main problem is that for modals no any show animations.